# Using AWS Cognito over Express-Session for session management

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito, express-session

I am using AWS Cognito in my application to authenticate users. AWS provides us with JWT token. My question is do we need to use express-session for handling session management, or will the JWT token provided by AWS Cognito take care of session management for authenticated users.

Comment: what you mean by "session management for authenticated users" ? Do you want to temporary cache the authenticated identity to speed up subsequent requests ? Or are you referring to a stateful jwt ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use Cognito JWT tokens, you don't need an explicit session handler.

You can send the JWT token to the client side and store it in the web browser (Local storage, Session storage or Cookie) which provides the persistence of the state(Acts as the session and will be valid for the token duration).

For all the subsequent requests you need to send the JWT in authorization headers back to your express server.

This is will have advantages over the sessions where if your API is consumed by clients other than web browsers such as mobile apps where it enables to implement unified state management.

To minimize the risk of storing id tokens in the LocalStorage for applications that requires high security, make the token duration small and generate new tokens using a refresh token.

Note:  You will need to use Cognito Autorization code grant flow to get the refresh token if you use the Cognito Hosted UI .

Comment: I would argue that exposing JWT to the web browser and using it for sessions is dangerous since it opens things up for the session hijacking.  I would recommend not to mix up the authentication and the session management.

Comment: @galaxy This is an never ending topic which will basically add subjective opinions. I have done though checks before answering. I can point you to two different references( Read more than 25+) which goes towards and against the answer I provided. Towards - https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/ and against - http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/. I had to evaluate the approach for an enterprise client so I have consulted security experts also to the topic. I can share further info if you need. Check the updated answer for more details.

Comment: your second link is actually the only one on the topic and was written by somebody who actually understands the distinction between *authentication* and the maintenance of a session. Auth0's one is weird they confuse the authentication process with the session management and all the issues come from that confusion. A session does not care whether you are authenticated or not - it is just supposed to carry over the defined state (where you can actually store an attribute that the entity was authenticated).